function keeps returning a monostate std::variant variable (a type not found within the alternative type parameters given to said variant)
so basically I am stumbling around a problem with one of my class implementations in c++, here are the functions that the issue is stemming from.
Interpreter.cpp:

using T = variant<double, string, bool, nullptr_t>;

double Interpreter::negateDouble(T value) const {
    return visit([](const auto& right) -> double {
        if constexpr (is_same_v<decltype(value), string>){
            return -right;
        }   

        throw runtime_error("Operand must be numbers.");         
    }, value);
}

string Interpreter::NormalizeDouble(const string& txt) const {
    string strBuilder = "";

    bool atDot = false;
    bool isAllZeros = false;
    bool isDecimal = false;

    for(const char& c : txt) {
        if(c == '.') {
            atDot = true;
        }

        if(!atDot) {
            strBuilder += c;
        } else {
            if(c == '0') isAllZeros = true;
            else if((c >= '0' && c <= '9') && c != '0')  {
                isAllZeros = false;
                isDecimal = true;
            }

            if(!isAllZeros) {
              strBuilder += c;  
            }
        }
    }

    if(isAllZeros && !isDecimal) strBuilder += "0";

    return strBuilder;
}

string Interpreter::to_string(T value) const {
        return visit(
        [&](const auto& val) -> string {
            if constexpr (is_same_v<decltype(val), string>){
                return val;
            } else if constexpr (is_same_v<decltype(val), bool>) {
                return val ? "true" : "false";
            } else if constexpr (is_same_v<decltype(val), double>) {
                cout << "its double!" << endl;
                return NormalizeDouble(to_string(val));
            } else if constexpr (is_same_v<decltype(val), nullptr_t>) {
                return "nil";
            }

            throw runtime_error("wrong Type of T detected");
        },
        value);
}

T Interpreter::evaluate(const Expr& expr) {
    if (auto binary = dynamic_cast<const Binary*>(&expr)) {
        return evalBinaryExpr(*binary);
    } else if (auto grouping = dynamic_cast<const Grouping*>(&expr)) {
        return evalGroupingExpr(*grouping);
    } else if (auto literal = dynamic_cast<const Literal*>(&expr)) {
        cout << "its literal" << endl;
        return evalLiteralExpr(*literal);
    } else if (auto unary = dynamic_cast<const Unary*>(&expr)) {
        cout << "its Unary" << endl;
        return evalUnaryExpr(*unary);
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported expression type.");
    }
}

T Interpreter::evalLiteralExpr(const Literal& expr) {
    return expr.value;
}

T Interpreter::evalGroupingExpr(const Grouping& expr) {
    return evaluate(*expr.expression);
}

T Interpreter::evalUnaryExpr(const Unary& expr) {
    T right = evaluate(*expr.right);

    switch(expr.oprator->type) {
        case MINUS:
            cout << "There is a minus!" << endl;
            if (std::holds_alternative<double>(right)) {
                std::cout << "Type is double before returning from MINUS" << std::endl;
            } else if (std::holds_alternative<bool>(right)) {
                std::cout << "Type is bool before returning from MINUS" << std::endl;
            } else if (std::holds_alternative<std::string>(right)) {
                std::cout << "Type is string before returning from MINUS" << std::endl;
            } else if (std::holds_alternative<std::nullptr_t>(right)) {
                std::cout << "Type is nullptr_t before returning from MINUS" << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cout << "Unknown type in MINUS case!" << std::endl;
            }

            return negateDouble(right);
        case BANG:
            return isTruthy(right);
        default:
            return static_cast<nullptr_t>(nullptr);
    }
}

main.cpp:

...
else if(command == "evaluate") {
        string file_contents = read_file_contents(argv[2]);

        Scanner scanner(file_contents);
        if(scanner.getErrStatus())
            return 65;

        Parser parser(scanner.getTokens());
        Interpreter interpret;
        try {
            T eval = interpret.evaluate(*parser.parse());
            cout << interpret.to_string(eval) << endl;
            parser.cleanUpExpressions();
        } catch (runtime_error& err) {
            parser.cleanUpExpressions();
            cerr << err.what();
            return 65;
        }
    }

...

when i run this:

./interpreter evaluate test.lox


this is my output

Logs from your program will appear here!

its Unary

its literal

There is a minus!

Type is double before returning from MINUS

Operand must be numbers.


but what i am expecting is:

Logs from your program will appear here!

its Unary

its literal

There is a minus!

Type is double before returning from MINUS

- 267.123


where in the main i am evaluating the expressions by parsing them first then passing them into the evaluate function of the interpreter object, but the thing here is the eval variable doesn't hold any type in the T variant when being returned from the evalUnaryExpr function, interesting thing here is that variant right in said function holds the alternative type of double as evident from the "Type is double before returning from MINUS" output on the console before returning but all of a sudden it loses it when it returns it.
What am I doing wrong here? could it just be an object destructing once it goes outta scope??

In your Interpreter::negateDouble() function, why do you check for is_same_v<decltype(value), string>, if right is supposed to contain a double?

value is the variant BTW, you should check right, i.e. is_same_v<decltype(right), double>

@heapunderrun i noticed the error and changed it to a double but it doesn't fix it

@Jarod42 thanks for the observation! i actually didn't see that, however it still doesn't quite fix the issue, i did recompile it and rerun it but still to no avail.

Run with your debugger. you should be able to see value of value and type of selected right.

@Jarod42 i also did -std::get(right) instead of negateDouble(right) and it still doesn't work.

It should be is_same_v<decltype(right), const double&> Demo. or is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(right)>, double>

@Jarod42  the program was confusing Interpreter::to_string and std::to_string as one function and so it kept on recursively calling the former in its own body... so I changed normalizeDouble(to_string(val)) to normalizeDouble(std::to_string(val)). thanks to your debugger tip, it helped me reach that conclusion eventually. i guess that should serve as a reminder to me to not use "using namespace std;" on big c++ projects in the future lol.

using namespace std; is not in the code provided.  A [mcve] should have included that important detail.
